# Chrome Extension for loop when next page is loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, dom-manipulation

I am having an issue with my chrome extension for loop. Currently, it is used to submit a form multiple times (this happens in content2.js, which utilizes the i value (via "iter") and it is returning the i value in the console.log).

I have tried to troubleshoot and what seems to be happening is that it is breaking out of the for loop immediately. Any assistance is welcome. Thanks guys.

```
for(var i = 0; i<inputSplit.length; i++){

chrome.storage.sync.set({"iter": i},function(){      
})

function x (callback){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
        file: "content2.js"
    });
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}


function y(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
        code: "document.querySelectorAll(\"a\")[1].click()"
    });
}


x(y);
}
```

Comment: I might add a delay function to iterate through i because I think it might be iterating before the functions in "content2.js" have ended.

Comment: Since the extension API is asynchronous it's best to use Promise to properly chain the calls, including the loop. There are lots of tutorials for that. Use Mozilla's polyfill for WebExtensions instead of promisifying the API manually.

Comment: I got it working with a couple call back functions in combination with timeouts but it is risky as the timer is based on average page load time. But thanks for the tip, I will try that now.